# How does Doctrine 2 retrieve entities without calling the entity's constructor?

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

Does anyone know how this works?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This works by [unserializing](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) objects. Unserializing in PHP does prevent the constructor to be called as the serialized object has been already constructed.

#### Create an object without calling it's constructor in PHP:

```
$className = 'stdClass'; # set classname here
$serialized = sprintf('O:%d:"%s":0:{}', strlen($className), $className);
$object = unserialize($serialized);
```

For more details please see this article: [Doctrine 2: Give me my constructor back](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine-2-give-me-my-constructor-back.html)

Comment: thx for the explanation and link.  I had no idea you could create an instance of an object like this!  I'm assuming that the format: "O:%d:"%s":0:{}", is the serialized format of an object?

Comment: @blacktie24: Yes it is. However if the object has properties and inheritance, it can differ. Additionally objects implementing the `serializeable` interface differ as well.

Comment: interesting, really appreciate the followup comment, I'll definitely mess around with serialized objects to see what the differences are with the variable setups.  Cheers.

Comment: If you want to nicely inspect serialized data, checkout the [Serialized PHP library](https://github.com/ktomk/Serialized). It can pretty print serialized objects and data. And it can create serialized objects more fine-grained as well.

Comment: Now I have a question, how can I ask Doctrine to call the constructor before hydration when fetching the result ?  I have some initialisation work in the constructor.

Comment: oh, I've just found it, i can use the postLoad doctrine event. cheers!