# Why __construct method don't work in User Entity in FOSUserBundle?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, construct

I am using the FOSUserBundle.

This is the `User` Entity:

```
namespace Shop\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    protected $shop;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->shop = 'shop';
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getShop()
    {
        return $this->shop;
    }
}
```

When I call `getShop` in the controller:

```
$user = $this->getUser()->getShop()
```

A result is null
Why does not `__construct` work in `User` class?
I expected to have 'shop' string as default

Comment: Are you sure `$this->getUser()` does what you think it does? You provide no code, so I can only assume that it retrieves an existing user rather than calling `new` therefore it is expected that `__construct()` is not triggered. Try `$user = new \Shop\UserBundle\Entity\User(); $user->getShop();` to see if it works...

Comment: yes. it's work's. But, if i use $this->getUser()->getShop() it doesn't work. But get_class($this->getUser()) - 'Shop\UserBundle\Entity\User'

Comment: As the answer below says, you have to add the property to the mapping, e.g. by adding annotations, and then updating the schema: `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`. Otherwise your property won't be saved and therefore will be null when you retrieve a previously persisted user.

Answer (score 3):

You can put a callback to iniatilize your User. Just two annotations **@ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks** for the entity and **@ORM\PostLoad** for the method. For example:

```
namespace Shop\UserBundle\Entity;
use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    protected $shop;

    /**
     * @ORM\PostLoad
     */
    public function init()
    {
        $this->shop = 'shop';
        parent::init();
    }

    public function getShop()
    {
        return $this->shop;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically __construct in doctrine entity is called directly in end user code. Doctrine does not use construct when fetch entities from database - please check [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944946/instantiate-an-object-without-calling-its-constructor-in-php) for more details. You can persist this in database by adding mapping if you want.