# How is it possible to populate private properties of php objects quickly?

Tags: php, doctrine

I would like to create some class instances from php associative arrays. I need to create the object without calling the constructor, and then set its properties.

I was able to find the [doctrine/instantiator](https://github.com/doctrine/instantiator/), which does the object creation.

Unfortunately [it is not able to set the properties](https://github.com/doctrine/instantiator/issues/21). How is it possible? How does Doctrine hydrator solve this?

I could create a `ReflectionClass`, get the reflectionProperty, call `->setAccessible(true)`, and then set the attribute. But for thousands of objects, this solution is too slow.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you need to do this. You could simply extend the class with a public hydrator method if using the constructor is not an option (why?). If speed is a concern and objects are in the thousands, using a library rig for the job seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: Because I have to build a library, and I don't know the classes before

Comment: may be this could help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944946/instantiate-an-object-without-calling-its-constructor-in-php  if you create a serialized object from your array and then unserialize it

Comment: If you don't know the classes before, how will you know the properties to be set?

Comment: @MarkusAO From an associative array.

Comment: I don't follow why one would want to hydrate unknown classes. A class typically has a particular purpose and a matching set of properties. Here you have (presumably) known variables that you want to hydrate into unknown classes as private properties. Further, how does doing that accomplish the building of a library?