# Class Table Inheritance Mapping in Doctrine 2: How to get type info from entity

Tags: doctrine-orm

With class table inheritance,

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"person" = "Person", "employee" = "Employee"})
 */
class Person
```

How can I get the type info from the entity? Since `discr` is a database column but not a property of the entity?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create abstract method `getKind()` in parent class and implement it in subclasses like

```
public function getKind()
{
  return 'employee';
}
```

Comment: I actually had a `$type` property, which is set in inheriting class in constructors. I noticed constructor doesnt get called when retrieving from database/entity manager? I'll use your method instead

Comment: Doctrine does not call constructor http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555237/how-does-doctrine-2-retrieve-entities-without-calling-the-entitys-constructor