# Builder pattern with Datamappers

Tags: php, domain-driven-design, entities

I'm currently working my way through a project and I'm trying to use DDD principals as much as possible.

I've implemented some entities, value objects, factories, builders and just started out with dependency injection for services. I can clearly see the benefit to doing things the DDD way.

I'm at the point where I'm going to need to start working on the data access layer. I'm a bit confused about the implementation. I want to use the repository pattern but I'm a bit stuck on how to get the objects from the database, to the entity. I assume I should use my builder classes, but how to I get them in my data access layer. Should I instantiate a new instance of a builder inside a Repository? I don't think dependency injection should be used here (or is that wrong?)

I'm using PHP for my project so PHP examples would be nice but psuedocode or C# is probably OK too.

Basically what I am a bit confused about is where to put the code that will build up an object from the database in my data access layer.

Answer (score 1):

In the repositories, you'd typically not use a builder to construct your entities.

Builders are usually used to limit the number of constructors a class provides when there are many possible ways to instantiate an object and are therefore used at object creation, at the beginning of the life-cycle of the entity in question.  On the other hand, the responsibility of a repository is not to construct new instances, but rather to dehydrate and hydrate existing objects (in the middle of the entities' life cycle).

There is a fine line here between these two approaches, since due to technical reasons in the programming language used (e.g., Java), hydration sometimes involves some constructor, too.  However, the constructor used upon object creation enforces class invariants; hydration, on the other hand, often simply uses a default constructor that does not enforce class invariants and sets the properties by direct access (e.g., by reflection in languages that support that).  A common PHP ORM mapper, Doctrine, can even hydrate objects via deserialization and thus does not need to call the constructor at all, [see this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555237/how-does-doctrine-2-retrieve-entities-without-calling-the-entitys-constructor).

If you are just starting with DDD, I can recommend to use an ORM mapper for your repository implementation; it's usually not a good idea to implement these things manually at the very beginning.